# EmberJS TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'reject'

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, ember.js

i've setup this app with ember and i'm getting this weird message:

**TypeError: Object # has no method 'reject'**

here's my EmberJS app config:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        namespace: '6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b'
    })
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('collections');
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function(){
        this.transitionTo('collections');
    }
});

App.CollectionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Collection.find();
    }
});

App.Collection = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    createdAt: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seams to be that you are using the wrong ember/ember-data files combinations... this should work:

http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest.js
http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.js

you can get here the latest builds: http://builds.emberjs.com

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks :) but this is actually the combination I was using :(

Comment: strange... here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AywvW/18/ with that combination working perfectly. can you setup a jsfiddle showing your index.html file and what you are loading?

Comment: nop :( weird thing is, with basic things that don't require the ember-data, it works perfectly, like the guide on their site know :s

Comment: sorry, I've update my answer... this (http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest.js) is the ember.js version you need to use in order to have it work correctly.

Comment: Ok, nevermind :) with [http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest.js](http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest.js) worked ;o thanks for the help!