# Ember Route model issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ember.js, ember-data, rails-api

I am following a tutorial by Brian Cadarella on DockYard.
Building an Ember app with Rails-api backend.
http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ember/2013/01/09/building-an-ember-app-with-rails-api-part-2.html

As soon as I change:

```
App.UsersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('users', model)
    @controllerFor('application').set('currentRoute', 'users')
```

To:

```
App.UsersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.User.find()
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('users', model)
    @controllerFor('application').set('currentRoute', 'users')
```

My link to the users page does not work. I get the following error in my firebug console:

```
TypeError: Ember.RSVP.reject is not a function
[Break On This Error]   
return Ember.RSVP.reject(error);
```

Ember.RSVP.reject is in ember-data.js

Why is it not working? I have been following that tutorial word for word.

Comment: This other answer of my is maybe of help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368964/emberjs-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-reject/16369039#16369039 I'm sure if you update your dependencies everything will work.

Comment: Be Ee Aye Utiful. It's working now thank you.

Comment: I'll posted it as an answer so you can accept it if it was useful :) thanks!

Comment: I tried, I don't have the 15 reputation points to upvote but I gave you the green checkmark haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This other answer of my is maybe of help for you [EmberJS TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'reject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368964/)… I'm sure if you update your dependencies everything will work.